# Typescript - custom Database class with Transaction capability

Tags: typescript, class, oop

I have a custom Database class which is simply a wrapper around a postgres connection and some queries.

```
export default class Database {
  private pool: Pool;

  constructor(pool: Pool) {
    this.pool = pool;
  }

  public async someQuery(params: ISomeQueryParams) {
    // do some query
  }
}
```

I would like to bring in transaction capability to this class. What I would like to achieve as an end result:

- For non-transactional queries

```
const db = new Database(pool);
await db.someQuery(params);
```

- For transactional queries

```
const tx = db.startTx(); // db is a Database instance
await tx.someQuery(params);
```

And I would like to achieve this without having to write duplicate code.

I have come up with 2 incomplete solutions:

**1. Self Factory Class**

The field `pool` is now `client`, which can be both a pool connection or a single connection. And the class now have a method which starts a tx, and creates a new instance of itself with that tx.

```
export default class Database {
  private client: Pool | PoolClient;

  constructor(client: Pool | PoolClient) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public async someQuery(params: ISomeQueryParams) {
    // do some query
  }

  public async startTx(): Database {
    const tx = await this.client.connect();
    await tx.query('BEGIN');
    return new Database(tx);
  }
}
```

Of course methods such as commitTx, rollbackTx are necessary, but this should be a sufficient example.

Drawbacks of this method is:

- Database instances with no transaction clients have access to methods specifically implemented for transactions, and vice-verse.

**2. Tx Factory Class**

Now, there is another class called Transaction, and the tx generation method of Database generates this class. Thus, the drawback of solution #1 has been overcome since each class will have only methods relevant to themselves.

```
export default class Database {
  private pool: Pool;

  constructor(pool: Pool) {
    this.pool = pool;
  }

  public async someQuery(params: ISomeQueryParams) {
    // do some query
  }

  public async startTx(): Transaction {
    const tx = await this.client.connect();
    return new Transaction(tx);
  }
}

class Transaction {
  private client: PoolClient;

  constructor(client: PoolClient) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public async begin() {
    await this.client.query('BEGIN');
  }

  public async someQuery(params: ISomeQueryParams) {
    // do some query
  }
}
```

Drawback of this method is:

- Each query function has to be duplicated on both of the classes

Any help to overcome this issue is very much appreciated.